Calliper carrier/braket pushes onto brake disc
like the title says, I have a brake calliper that pushes on the disc and blocks it.
Context: Skoda Octavia 2, 1z3 bkd. I am trying to change my discs and pads, on the calliper carrier it took a great deal to remove the m14 bolts, I bought a 1800nm pneumatic driver and it still didn't work until I used a big bar with a 2.5 ton jack and then I successfully loosened the bolts.
I put the new disc, new pads and then the calliper carrier back, after I screwed the bolts, the calliper was seizing my disc making it unable to move. The disc is same size as the old one, messured.
What can I do in this situation and what could've caused this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Excuse the t-shirt I caught it by accident a few times in the drilling machine. :)
These are the two carriers/brackets, one derusted one rusted. I also tried with all bolts screwed on the disc to make sure it is flushed. The only possible answer for me would be that the mechanic that worked on the disc before screwed the bolts on the carriers too tight, which I heard on the internet that it might bend the carrier itself. Strange as it is a huge piece of metal, but... other explanation doesn't exist for me. And there's the fact that I had to use more than 1800 NM to unscrew them, and their spec is at 143NM...
OK, it was the wrong disc, apparently there are 2 versions for this model of car...








As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Welcome, but this isn't an answer. Please edit your question to add more detail, and try to avoid posting multiple pictures of the same thing.
